# Custom model binder doesn't affect properties in ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: c#, .net-core, model-binding, asp.net-core-3.1, .net-core-3.1

I'm trying to develop some custom model binder for some specified properties e.g. properties with type `string`. I have this simple binder and provider:

```
public class CustomModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider {
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context) {
        if (context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(string)) 
            return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder));
        return null;
    }
}

public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder {
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        // blah blah blah
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

And I registered the binder at startup:

```
services.AddMvc(o => {o.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new CustomModelBinderProvider());})
        .AddControllersAsServices();
```

Here is a simple model and action I'm testing with:

```
public class Man {
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class MyController : ControllerBase {

    [HttpPost]
    public object Des(Man model) {
        return new {Me = "amiry", Man = model};
    }
}
```

But when I post a model e.g.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "phone": "some string"
}
```

to the action, the `CustomModelBinderProvider.GetBinder` get hitted once, and the `context.Metadata.ModelType`'s value is always `Man` class. While I expect for each property it get called. So, how can I have a model binder to bind each property separately? I know that I can annotate properties with attributes. But I don't want to put some attributes on each property I want to act on. I'm looking for a way to bind properties with a binder with just some settings in startup - like above. Have any idea please?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @RaviMPatel Unfortunately not yet ): I had to change the entire code.

Comment: I had a custom binder for date. Was facing same issue. I could solve it by creating a custom JsonConverter for DateTime. Registered it in Startup.cs and it solve the problem. thanks

Comment: @RaviMPatel I had to move to custom converters too; but it's not the answer. Binding issue is still not-resolved.

Comment: If you post json data, then json formatter (converter) will be used instead of the model binder.  Make sure the content-type of the http request is not `application/json` in order for the default or custom model binder to work on.

Comment: @StackUndefined Thanks for your comment. This is a very old question and I cant remember what happened next. Please let me to check it out.